# datetimepicker add default date to next month

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Going straight to the point here.

is there a way for me to get the default month of the datetimepicker to next month?

here's what I've done so far

```
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        startDate: '2017-12-01',
        endDate: '2018-01-31',
        format: "MM dd, yyyy HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true
    });
```

when I open the datetimepicker it opens the december 01 - 31, 2017. is there a way for me to show january 01-31, 2018?

Comment: @Preet already tried it.. still doesn't work

Comment: after looking into the documentation I found this on this property `initialDate` 
 ont the `options`.. this do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [this CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) for jQuery, [this CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js) for the datetime plugin, and [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css) are the styles.

#### HTML

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

#### JavaScript

```
var defaultDate = '2018/01/31';
var defaultTime = '05:00';

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

$(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker').val(defaultDate + " " + defaultTime)
})
```

I am using jQuery to set the initial input value. The datetimepicker will automatically take the input value as the default date & time.

Take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nipunasudha/b2hew1o7/7/)

Comment: I did not understand you want different defaults. Please refine your question, I'll work on a solution

Comment: I already look the documentation of the plugin and I already found a solution `initialDate`. thank you for your help though.

Comment: You are welcome, and please add the solution as an answer or an edit.

Answer (score 0):

upon reading the documentation of the plugin I found an answer.

`initialDate`

Date or String. Default: new Date()

You can initialize the viewer with a date. By default it's now, so you can specify yesterday or today at midnight ...

```
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        initialDate: '2018-01-01',
        startDate: '2017-12-01',
        endDate: '2018-01-31',
        format: "MM dd, yyyy HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true
    });
```